# How to transfer synced blockchain along with another OS on a USB

Tags: security, blockchain, daemon, operating-system

So, I am considering switching my current OS to Qubes and I am currently running Lubuntu 14.04 LTS.  I figured since Qubes is a lot more secure of an OS, I wanted to install it on my laptop as my main OS I use to have a "fresh" install feeling, and to feel a little more secure with my funds being on there.

I would prefer not to re download the entire blockchain from scratch; so how can I save the already synced blockchain I have onto a USB along with Qubes so I can use it right after installation?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you will use the environment based on Debian or Fedora. In that case, you can copy the current .bitmonero to the equivalent location on Qubes. 
When you re-run bitmonerod, it will continue as it would have on your Lunbuntu system.

There is no need for a specific verification of the chain since you trust the provide of the file (yourself).